# Show a link in fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

When I try to display a link in pdf it does not show me the link, but the php code or string text are displayed. How can I change that?

**This is my code**

```
while($fila2 = mysql_fetch_array($fila)) {
    $item = $item+1;    
    $pdf->Cell(5, 8 ,$item, 1);
    $pdf->Cell(10, 8 ,$fila2['FOLIO'], 1);
    $pdf->Cell(70, 8 ,$fila2['NOMBRE'], 1);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 8 ,date("d-m-Y",strtotime($fila2['FECHA_SOLICITUD'])), 1);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 8 ,$fila2['TIPO_AUTORIZACION'], 1);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 8 ,date("d-m-Y",strtotime($fila2['FECHA_AUTORIZACION'])), 1);
    $pdf->Cell(20,8 , '<a href="http://www.intranet.com/mb/rprh06/final.php?folio=$fila2["FOLIO"]" target="_blank">Enlace</a>',1); 
    $pdf->Ln(8);
}
```

**And this is my result**

[image]

I want to show something like "View Link" according to the result ID of the row. But when I pass the pointer on the link it shows the following

[image]

Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the link:- http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/link.htm

You need to write like this:-

```
$pdf->Link(100,10,10,10, 'http://www.intranet.com/mb/rprh06/final.php?folio='.$fila2[‌​"FOLIO"]);
```

Or with `Cell()`:-

```
$pdf->Cell(20,8 ,'','','','',false, "http://www.intranet.com/mb/rprh06/final.php?folio=".$fila2["FOLIO"]);
```

Reference:- http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/cell.htm

Note:- change parameters values accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. Cell works for me but  the large link appears.. and dont show like a link, I read the documentation but I have many questions. Thank You.

$pdf->Cell(30,8 ,"http://www.intranet.com/mb/rprh06/final.php?folio=".$fila2["FOLIO"],1);

Comment: @JuanPabloBustamanteLuna  you can adjust values to make it smaller (check parameters and change the value)

Comment: @JuanPabloBustamanteLuna If you want link blue, try `$pdf->SetTextColor(6, 69, 173);`, afterwards return it to black with `$pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);`